# How to block my app users to temporarily updating my app on Playstore

Tags: android, google-play-console

Lack of attention, i just made a big mistake.I deployed a new version of my application on playstore. I made a mistake to change the type of a data in my sharedPreferences, for some reason. Now all my current users who make update get ClassCastException crash when they try to open the app.

Now I fixed the problem and sent a new new version, but lately Google takes up to 3 days to process the updates rollouts. I can't wait until 3 days, i have already had negatives feedback's.

I wonder if there is a way to block my current users to temporarily updating my app on play console.

Please need help

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is not much you can do about it. Only to answer the bad reviews and inform users, that an update is pending. If you have some remote notification technique (like fcm), you could inform them about it, too.

Comment: Lesson: Never roll out to 100% instantly.

Comment: humm i suspected it. Thanks bro, for your quick reply. I have no more choice, i will wait and reply to reviews.